# Characters not displayed in UI after waking from suspend : Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, 16.04

I am getting this second day in row after waking up PC from suspend:

[image: what a mess]

Tried `compiz` --replace but all system hanged up.

Anybody knows how to fix it?

Running Ubuntu 16.04 with all latest updates on Lenovo T440p.

**UPDATE:**

This happens only if I forget to turn off sshuttle and/or cos (snx). And there is something about newroking in the syslog wich can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw7zEiUzSEYBYVlYc3JoU01lajA/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0):

See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes :

Sometimes Gtk application menus go missing https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1532226. You can workaround this by launching this from a terminal or Alt+F2 dash view:
restart unity-panel-service

Comment: thank you for helping, but, well, the menus are actually where they shoul d be, it's windows content  which is screwed.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: i am having same issue, also on lenovo. Did you find a solution without rebooting?