# Display/graphics problem: characters disappear (Ubuntu 16.04.)

Tags: 16.04, unity, lubuntu

I periodically experience a weird graphics error where nearly all text characters disappear. In windows's titles, menu items, text in terminal or emacs, most characters are gone **except** some characters that seem to be left in all instances, e.g., all c's or v's are still visible. Everything else works just fine.

In some instances menu text appears as greyed out (or maybe the text's special attributes/shadows are maintained while the characters themselves are missing). See screenshot for details (I'll provide more once it returns)

[image: Y and N characters scattered over a black window with blank titlebar and empty tabs]

It happens with Ubuntu 16.04.1 both with unity and LXDE/Openbox.

It's the same problem as here [Characters not displayed in UI after waking from suspend : Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777645/characters-not-displayed-in-ui-after-waking-from-suspend-ubuntu-16-04), but not limited to wake up from suspend.

On my Lenovo Thinkpad T530i running Lubuntu 16.04 (64 bit), those are my GPU specs:

```
sudo lshw -numeric -C display:
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:116]
   vendor: Intel Corporation [8086]
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 09
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:27 memory:f0000000-f03fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:5000(size=64)
```

on my partner's Thinkpad T530 running Unity (also 64 bit) output is the same except for

```
product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
```

but the problem is the same.

Comment: Can you tell a bit more about your computer (notably the GPU you have)?